# Why would a sql query have "where 1 = 1"

Tags: sql, where-clause

I was going through a few queries I am maintaining, and a programmer had put in the queries "where 1=1"  to me that always seems to evaluate to true.

Are there benefits to this?

**Duplicate:** [Why would someone use WHERE 1=1 AND  in a SQL clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242822/why-would-someone-use-where-11-and-conditions-in-a-sql-clause)

That question isn't an answer to this question.

Where-clause:

```
select * from table where 1=1 and sStatus not in ('status1','status2','status3')
```

No programming or if statements to push an and in there.  A straight query.

If you could un-close this, I would like to know whether there is a purpose so that I may rewrite and remove the 1=1 if it is unnecessary.

Comment: No purpose that I can see, and judging by the accepted answer in the link it seems the 1=1 will be optimized out. Probably someone did a little cut'n'paste programming.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Was it dynamic queries? Sometimes that's helpful when building dynamic queries based on parameters that are optional.

Answer (score 19):

If you automatically want to add restrictions to your query, it makes your life easier:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1=1";

if (someflag) {
  sql += " AND valid = 1";
}

if (someotherflag) {
  sql += " AND special = 1";
}

execute(sql);
```

Without `WHERE 1 = 1` you would in each case have to check if it's the first restriction you add (and then use `WHERE ...`) or if you already added some other restriction before (and then add `AND ...`).

Answer (score 12):

If you are dynamically building a where clause, you can be a bit lazy and assume that every clause you add can be prefixed with "AND", e.g.

```
$str="select foo from bar where 1=1";

if ($filter1)
{
    $str.=" and col1='frobozz'";
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I use this for dynamic where clauses when I'm doing some lazy programming and don't want to always check if the clause is empty to determine if I now need an "AND" between my dynamic clauses.

Answer (score 4):

This really only makes sense in dynamic queries. If you are adding parameters in a loop instead of having to check if there is a WHERE already you can just append AND Column = Value every time.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen two reasons for this, when you always want a true result, or when there is going to be an arbitrary number of "and condition = value" appended to the statement

Answer (score 0):

That is very interesting... The WHERE clause contains nothing but 1=1? I have seen this frequently in SQL injection attempts in which the WHERE clause is set to 

`xyz="something" OR 1=1;`

as a means to always return a list of results.

Can you tell us more about what is going on with this query so we might be able to answer the question better?

- Nicholas