# What is the purpose of using WHERE 1=1 in SQL statements?

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, where-clause

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Why would a sql query have “where 1 = 1”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517107/why-would-a-sql-query-have-where-1-1)
>   [Why would someone use WHERE 1=1 AND <conditions> in a SQL clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242822/why-would-someone-use-where-11-and-conditions-in-a-sql-clause)

I've seen that a lot in different query examples and it goes to probably all SQL engines.

If there is a query that has no conditions defined people (and specially ORM frameworks) often add always-true condition `WHERE 1 = 1` or something like that.

So instead of

```
SELECT id, name FROM users;
```

they use

```
SELECT id, name FROM users WHERE 1 = 1;
```

The only possible reason I could think of if you are adding conditions dynamically you don't have to worry about stripping the initial `AND` but still quite often this `1 = 1` condition is stripped if there is an actual condition in the query.

Actual example from CakePHP (generated by framework):

(no conditions)

```
SELECT `User`.`id`, `User`.`login`
FROM `users` AS `User` WHERE 1 = 1 
ORDER BY `User`.`id` ASC;
```

(with condition)

```
SELECT `User`.`id`, `User`.`login`
FROM `users` AS `User` 
WHERE `User`.`login` = 'me@example.com'
LIMIT 1;
```

Is there any reason for adding that extra condition?

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517107/why-would-a-sql-query-have-where-1-1 among others

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yeah, it's typically because it starts out as 'where 1 = 0', to force the statement to fail.

It's a more naive way of wrapping it up in a transaction and not committing it at the end, to test your query. (This is the preferred method).

Comment: There can be more than one answer; and in this case the OP was specific that it wasn't just for building dynamic queries (and honestly, if you're building dynamic queries in these days of ORMs, take a good hard look at yourself).

Answer (score 66):

It's also a common practice when people are **building the sql query programmatically**, it's just easier to start with 'where 1=1 ' and then appending ' and customer.id=:custId' depending if a customer id is provided.
So you can always append the next part of the query starting with 'and ...'.

Answer (score 42):

The **1=1** is ignored by always all rdbms. There is no tradeoff executing a query with **WHERE 1=1**.

Building dynamic WHERE conditions, like ORM frameworks or other do very often, it is easier to append the *real* where conditions because you avoid checking for prepending an **AND** to the current condition.

```
stmt += "WHERE 1=1";
if (v != null) {
   stmt += (" AND col = " + v.ToString());
}
```

This is how it looks like without 1=1.

```
var firstCondition = true;
...
if (v != null) {
   if (!firstCondition) {
      stmt += " AND ";
   }
   else {
       stmt += " WHERE ";
       firstCondition = false;
   }
   stmt += "col = " + v.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Actually, I tend to do something like: cmd = "select ..."; sep = " where "; foreach (cond) { cmd += sep + cond; sep = " and "; }

Comment: Which looks a *little* cleaner.

Comment: Good idea! I keep it in mind for further programming.

Comment: while this explains perfectly why my collogues are doing this, i keep wondering if this style of coding is good or not

Answer (score 28):

People use it because they're inherently lazy when building dynamic SQL queries. If you start with a `"where 1 = 1"` then all your extra clauses just start with `"and"` and you don't have to figure out.

Not that there's anything wrong with being inherently lazy. I've seen doubly-linked lists where an "empty" list consists of two sentinel nodes and you start processing at the `first->next` up until `last->prev` inclusive.

This actually removed all the special handling code for deleting `first` and `last` nodes. In this set-up, *every* node was a middle node since you weren't able to delete `first` or `last`. Two nodes were wasted but the code was simpler and (ever so slightly) faster.

The only other place I've ever seen the "1 = 1" construct is in BIRT. Reports often use positional parameters and are modified with Javascript to allow all values. So the query:

```
select * from tbl where col = ?
```

when the user selects `"*"` for the parameter being used for `col` is modified to read:

```
select * from tbl where ((col = ?) or (1 = 1))
```

This allows the new query to be used without fiddling around with the positional parameter details. There's still exactly one such parameter. Any decent DBMS (e.g., DB2/z) will optimize that query to basically remove the clause entirely before trying to construct an execution plan, so there's no trade-off.

Comment: Thanks dude! This was the most plausible answer!

Answer (score 3):

As you said:

> if you are adding conditions
>   dynamically you don't have to worry
>   about stripping the initial AND
>   that's the only reason could be, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Using 1=1 is actually not a very good idea as this can cause full table scans by itself.

See this--> [T-SQL 1=1 Performance Hit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049512/t-sql-11-performance-hit)

Comment: Only on the crappiest of DBMS'.

Comment: All the answeres in the question you linked to said 1=1 has no impact.