# SQL Server where clause using iif in store procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, where-clause, iif

I have a store procedure in SQL Server. I have a filtering page in my application, I want to select all `CDT_ID`, if I do not input the name and lower_age and upper_age, it will show all the `CDT_ID`. But if I input the name and age, it will show all the `CDT_ID` where `CDT_NAME` AND `CDT_AGE` range is like I input in the filtering column. My query is like in this below:

```
select CDT_ID from CANDIDATE 
where CDT_NAME LIKE iif(@name is null, '', @name)
AND CDT_NAME between (iif(@lower_age is null, '', @lower_age) and iif(@upper_age is null, '', @upper_age))
```

The problem is my query result show nothing when I execute my store procedure. And if I run the query without where it shows a lot of `CDT_ID`. Do you know how to fix my 'where' clauses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More than IIF, **[COALESCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql)** will work better here.
Also when using parameters in WHERE clause, typical syntax for WHERE clause is like

```
...
WHERE 1=1 AND p=@param
```

See **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264681/what-is-the-purpose-of-using-where-1-1-in-sql-statements)** for details

In your query CDT_AGE was not mentioned. I took liberty to correct it.

Here's a revised query

```
select 
    CDT_ID 
from CANDIDATE 
where 
    1=1
        AND
    CDT_NAME LIKE COALESCE(@name,CDT_NAME)
        AND
    CDT_AGE between COALESCE(@lower_age,0) AND COALESCE(@upper_age,1000)
```

Comment: I would strongly disagree that `WHERE 1=1` is *typical syntax* and even when used for creating dynamic conditions in an application it's still just being lazy. Simply add an `OR`ed condition and start wrapping it into `()`.

Answer (score 0):

You used CDT_NAME instead of CDT_AGE.

I don't know about your exact business rules, but instead of a proprietary `IIF` or a Standard SQL compliant `COALESCE` I would use a simple ORed condition (which might enable indexed access, too):

```
select CDT_ID 
from CANDIDATE 
where (@name is null and @lower_age is null and @upper_age is null)
   or (    CDT_NAME LIKE @name
       AND CDT_AGE between @lower_age AND @upper_age
      )
```

If you want to return all rows if either name or age is null you can modify it to:

```
where (@name is null or @lower_age is null or @upper_age is null)
```

Or you add some sanity check before the Select and apply a default value.
Or run two different Selects based on NULLs.