# In-memory database filtering by null value not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, in-memory-database

I've got a working piece of code, that I want to cover with unit tests. However Microsoft's in-memory database returns some unexpected values.

If I query like that

```
var count = query.Count(c => c.Birthday2000 != null);
```

the result is 0, although it should be 12.

If I query that way

```
var count = query.ToList().Count(c => c.Birthday2000 != null);
```

the result is 12, which was expected.

If I run it with my relational database (mysql) the first line works too.

I've got the following model

```
public class Customer
{
    public DateTime? BirthDay {get; set; }
    private DateTime? _birthday2000;
    public DateTime? BirthDay2000 
    {
        get
        {
            if (BirthDay == null) _birthday2000 = null;
            else _birthday2000 = new DateTime(2000, BirthDay.Value.Month, BirthDay.Value.Day);
            return _birthday2000;
        }
        set => _birthday2000 = value;
    }
}
```

What could cause that issue?

My goal is to query the database for the next n birthdays to come. I can't order and filter BirthDay, because the year-portion differs, that's why I introduced a BirthDay2000-property where the year gets set to a fixes year.

I used a custom g/setter to set it automatically when I receive new customers by a webservice.

Comment: When you use .ToList(), it will execute the query up to that point, so `query.ToList()` will return ALL records, THEN they will be counted.  As to why `Count(...)` doesn't work, your implementation of BirthDay2000 is 'complex', which can't be done by the database itself, so has to be done locally.

Comment: Do you have any manual configuration for the `Customer` model?

Comment: As @atiyar said it's possible it comes from the configuration and in same specific case EntityFramework will generate a "1:1" query because he knows the condition will never be reach (by example if it believe the date can never be null)... But I don't know much about the behavior of the in memory database
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264681/what-is-the-purpose-of-using-where-1-1-in-sql-statements

Answer (score 0):

Not only is your `BirthDay2000` invalid as far as mapping EF.Core to a database of any kind (ORMs use data objects, not logic objects), it's fairly invalid as far as properties go in general as well: your getter has side effects.

Comment: What I wanted to achieve is autoset the BirthDay2000-property dependent on the value of BirthDay. I edited my initial post to make it a bit clearer why.

Comment: The why doesn't matter, you're doing it very wrong. If you want dependent properties then use something already made, like OAPH. If you want to code them yourself, then fine, but don't write to variables *in your getter*. And if you want to use EF.Core, separate your Dto from your logic layer.