# Selecting Indexes based on Column/Table Names

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Is there a system SP or dmv that allows me to select indexes in my DB based on columns and table names?

What I am trying to do is to drop indexes based on columns with string datatypes as I am in the process of altering my collation settings.

Thanks.

Comment: You can try the query on this post...
[Query for listing columns, indices and constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51415260/1642932)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always determine the indices for a given column and/or table by querying the sys.indexes and sys.index_columns views:

```
SELECT
    i.Name 'Index Name',
    OBJECT_NAME(i.object_ID) 'Table Name',
    c.Name 'Column Name'
FROM  
   sys.indexes i 
INNER JOIN 
   sys.index_columns ic ON i.index_id = ic.index_id AND i.object_id = ic.object_id
INNER JOIN
   sys.columns c ON ic.column_id = c.column_id AND ic.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE 
  c.name = 'Index column name'      -- this for a column name
  -- OBJECT_NAME(i.OBJECT_ID) = 'Table Name'   -- this for table name
```

Marc

Answer (score 1):

you need four system views:

sys.indexes, sys.index_columns,    sys.columns and sys.objects.    sys.objects contains the name of    table, sys.columns. contains    object_id of table and type of    column, sys.index_columns contains    columns id that are present in    indexes and index id, sys.indexes    contains index id.

**edit:** yes, sys.objects is not necessary. Tanks @mark.