# Query to check index on a table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, indexing

I need a query to see if a table already has any indexes on it.

Comment: In postgres, it's just \d+ table, in MySQL is desc <TABLE>. In SQL server, it's convoluted as hell because Microsoft wants to make life hard for all of us!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of all index & index columns in SQL Server DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765867/list-of-all-index-index-columns-in-sql-server-db)

Answer (score 126):

On SQL Server, this will list all the indexes for a specified table:

```
select * from sys.indexes
where object_id = (select object_id from sys.objects where name = 'MYTABLE')
```

This query will list all tables without an index:

```
SELECT name
FROM sys.tables 
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id,'IsIndexed') = 0
```

And this is an interesting MSDN FAQ on a related subject:
[Querying the SQL Server System Catalog FAQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345522.aspx)

Comment: How do I see which columns these indexes have been placed on ?

Comment: Should be noted the top query will fail if the table has more than one index, Replace `object_id = (select` with `object_id IN (select` if you need to see the information about the indices, or just want the query to complete without error.

Comment: This answer should be replaced with @Tor's answer IMO.

Answer (score 43):

If you're using MySQL you can run `SHOW KEYS FROM table` or `SHOW INDEXES FROM table`

Comment: so sorry for not telling the environment. Its SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 31):

If you just need the indexed columns
EXEC sp_helpindex 'TABLE_NAME'

Answer (score 16):

Simply you can find index name and column names of a particular table using below command

`SP_HELPINDEX 'tablename'`

It works for me

Comment: Simple and the best!

Answer (score 8):

Most modern RDBMSs support the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` schema.  If yours supports that, then you want either `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS` or `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE`, or maybe both.

To see if yours supports it is as simple as running

`select count(*) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS`

EDIT: SQL Server does have `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, and it's easier to use than their vendor-specific tables, so just go with it.

Comment: As the name suggests, the ANSI standard view,
`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS` only shows constraints.  While some
constraints are indexes not all indexes are constraints. This view won’t
show regular indexes: it only displays `CONSTRAINT_TYPE`s of `UNIQUE`,
`PRIMARY KEY`, `FOREIGN KEY` or `CHECK`.  See [the relevant section from
“SQL-99 Complete,
Really”](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-99-complete-really/16-sql-catalogs/the-information-schema/information_schema-views/information_schematable_constraints/)

Answer (score 5):

Here is what I used for TSQL which took care of the problem that my table name could contain the schema name and possibly the database name:

```
DECLARE @THETABLE varchar(100);
SET @THETABLE = 'theschema.thetable';
select i.*
  from sys.indexes i
 where i.object_id = OBJECT_ID(@THETABLE)
   and i.name is not NULL;
```

The use case for this is that I wanted the list of indexes for a named table so I could write a procedure that would dynamically compress all indexes on a table.

Answer (score 4):

On Oracle:

- Determine all indexes on table:

  ```
  SELECT index_name 
   FROM user_indexes
   WHERE table_name = :table
  ```
- Determine columns indexes and columns on index:

  ```
  SELECT index_name
       , column_position
       , column_name
    FROM user_ind_columns
   WHERE table_name = :table
   ORDER BY index_name, column_order
  ```

References:

- [ALL_IND_COLUMNS](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10820/statviews_1099.htm#i1577532)
- [ALL_INDEXES](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10820/statviews_1105.htm#i1578369)

Answer (score 3):

First you check your table id (aka object_id)

```
SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'U' ORDER BY name
```

then you can get the column's names. For example assuming you obtained from previous query the number 4 as object_id

```
SELECT c.name
FROM sys.index_columns ic
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON  c.column_id = ic.column_id
WHERE ic.object_id = 4 
AND c.object_id = 4
```

Answer (score 3):

Created a stored procedure to list indexes for a table in database in SQL Server

```
create procedure _ListIndexes(@tableName nvarchar(200))
as
begin
/*
exec _ListIndexes '<YOUR TABLE NAME>'
*/
SELECT DB_NAME(DB_ID()) as DBName,SCH.name + '.' + TBL.name AS TableName,IDX.name as IndexName, IDX.type_desc AS IndexType,COL.Name as ColumnName,IC.*
    FROM sys.tables AS TBL 
         INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS SCH ON TBL.schema_id = SCH.schema_id 
         INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS IDX ON TBL.object_id = IDX.object_id 
         INNER JOIN sys.index_columns IC ON  IDX.object_id = IC.object_id and IDX.index_id = IC.index_id 
         INNER JOIN sys.columns COL ON ic.object_id = COL.object_id and IC.column_id = COL.column_id 
        where TBL.name = @tableName
    ORDER BY TableName,IDX.name

end
```

Answer (score 1):

check this as well
This gives an overview of associated constraints across a database.
Please also include facilitating where condition with table name of interest so gives information faster.

```
   select 
a.TABLE_CATALOG as DB_name,a.TABLE_SCHEMA as tbl_schema, a.TABLE_NAME as tbl_name,a. CONSTRAINT_NAME as constraint_name,b.CONSTRAINT_TYPE
 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE a
join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS b on
 a.CONSTRAINT_NAME=b.CONSTRAINT_NAME
```

Answer (score -2):

for smss - mssql, one can refer the create script[image]

Comment: Is this query ?? OP clearly asked for query to check index on a table