# Automatic index on a table

Tags: sql-server

I was trying to find out if any index is created on a table, automatically. I used this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800698/query-to-check-index-on-a-table) to find indexes on Employees table which has 4 columns, namely empid, empName, salary and dept. The query shows that table already has an index - I don't have keys on the table. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781088/does-sql-server-creates-non-clustered-index-on-all-columns-of-a-table-by-default) says that non-clustered indexes are not created automatically on a table. So what is the type of index that is already present on Employees table ? Also, index name is shown as null.

Create statement and query used to find indexes on Employees table are as follows :

```
 Create table Employees( 
      empid int,
      empName varchar(100),
      salary int,
      dept varchar(10)
    )

   select * from sys.indexes
   where object_id = (select object_id 
                     from sys.objects where name = 'Employees')
```

Comment: A primary key would add a unique index, to enforce the uniqueness.  empid is probably a primary key

Comment: I don't have primary key on the table. If it is of any help, index has been created on heap.

Comment: Can you share the create statement of the table, as well as the actual query you've used to find the indexes?

Comment: Added the queries. Also if it is of any help, the object explorer in SQL Server Management Studio, doesn't show any index on the table.

Comment: Per your query, no index is created unless you tell so.

Comment: Yes, but second query throws a row from sys.indexes table, when I try to find index on the table. Is the query showing index - Index name is null ?

Comment: This should also mean that no indexes are created automatically on a table ?

Comment: It's not the name of index - it's the name of *object* (field `object_id`), i.e. your database name. No index is created automatically until you tell so. Be aware that starting from SQL Server 2014 you can create inline indexes.

Comment: What is the value of  `type_desc` in your query results? I would expect that to be `HEAP`, which is the table itself because it has no clustered index. It's not really an index even though it's exposed in the `sys.indexes` catalog view.

Comment: @DanGuzman Was thinking the same. Yes, type_desc is Heap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the output from the `sys.indexes` query in your question:

```
+------------+------+----------+------+-----------+-----------+---------------+----------------+----------------+----------------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------------+-----------------+------------------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+---------------------------+--------------+
| object_id  | name | index_id | type | type_desc | is_unique | data_space_id | ignore_dup_key | is_primary_key | is_unique_constraint | fill_factor | is_padded | is_disabled | is_hypothetical | is_ignored_in_optimization | allow_row_locks | allow_page_locks | has_filter | filter_definition | compression_delay | suppress_dup_key_messages | auto_created |
+------------+------+----------+------+-----------+-----------+---------------+----------------+----------------+----------------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------------+-----------------+------------------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+---------------------------+--------------+
| 1746105261 | NULL |        0 |    0 | HEAP      |         0 |             1 |              0 |              0 |                    0 |           0 |         0 |           0 |               0 |                          0 |               1 |                1 |          0 | NULL              | NULL              |                         0 |            0 |
+------------+------+----------+------+-----------+-----------+---------------+----------------+----------------+----------------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------------+-----------------+------------------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+---------------------------+--------------+
```

Note the `type_desc` value is "HEAP", meaning a table without a clustered index. So the returned row is the table itself rather than an index. The [documentation for `sys.indexes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-indexes-transact-sql) states (my emphasis):

> Contains a row per index or **heap** of a tabular object, such as a table,
>   view, or table-valued function