# A WHERE clause that always selects all records in a table

Tags: sql, where-clause, resultset

I'm looking to create a function that generates an SQL query, filtering the results by an expression given as a parameter (which will passed as a 'WHERE' clause). If the parameter is omitted, all results are returned.

In order to do this I can test for a null parameter and only build the where clause if parameter is given (`where = (parameter != null) ? "" : "WHERE " + parameter`). However, I was thinking is there an expression that I can default to that will always return all results. This way I don't need to test to see whether to include the `WHERE` keyword (`where = "WHERE " + parameter`).

I've intentionally not mentioned escaping the parameter to avoid injection. I won't forget this in my solution, I promise! :)

Comment: What language are you using?  Or are you using proprietary SQL language (e.g. T-SQL) to generate the query? Please add tags

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8149183/27535

Comment: It is a proprietary SQL language, specific to the application I'm working with. It's quite possible that there may not be a way to do this, but I thought I'd find out the 'standard' way of doing this as a starting point.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I usually use `1 = 1` for that.

Answer (score 4):

```
(where = "WHERE 1 = 1 " + parameter)
```

In this case parameter should start with " AND " token.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize the parameter as `TRUE` or `1`.

Comment: Not all DBMSes support that, and the OP doesn't specify what DMBS (s)he's using.