# What are the practical uses of inserting "1==1" (1 is equal to 1) in conditional statements?

Tags: c#, javascript, conditional-operator

Sometimes in JavaScript or C# code I will see a "1==1" conditional statement.

C# example:

```
if (!IsPostBack || 1==1)
```

I know that in Sql statements, 1=1 can be used [when dynamically building queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149142/where-1-1-statement) or when creating sql injection attacks, but I don't understand the practical usage of a test that always evaluates to true in C# or JavaScript.

Comment: @dystroy: could you elaborate on that? How would the shown code be an error without it? I have never seen a usage such as the one you describe.

Comment: Sometimes people use a simple mathematical check like that while debugging to quickly force a block of code to run or prevent it from running (1==0) without altering anything else inside the statement.  It would be sloppy to leave it in there permanently.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no value. This makes the condition to be always true, so you simply could remove the `if`.

I guess it has been added while debugging a problem to force the execution of this particular branch and it simply has been forgotten to remove it. I would call it a bug.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance: What kind of question is that? You should be asking why it is there at all. `true` would have been just the same and both make no sense when being left permanently in the code. Why the developer chose to use `1==1` instead of `true` is impossible for me to know.

Answer (score 2):

Developer testing of the following:

- The function/method/sub/etc gets executed no matter the "Real" parameter value
- Seeing how your parameters would be effected by a False || True situation

The only real practical uses I see are:

- Testing
- SQL Injection, as you said

Answer (score 1):

An `if` with a `1==1` conditional is a misuse of an `if` statement. Although syntactically sound, it removes the value of the `if` even being there.

As Daniel stated, it was probably used while debugging a particular portion of code. If it's left in production code it is likely a bug, otherwise it's a complete misuse of the `if` statement.

```
if ( !IsPostBack || 1==1)
{
    // Do Something
}
```

is equivalent to

```
//Do Something
```