# IF rules $_POST PHP - MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, post, if-statement

**UPDATE**

I've improved my code to this:

```
$query_init = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE 1=1";


24 // $_POST to PHP var.
25 $t_bebida = $_POST['t_bebida'];
26 $t_uf = $_POST['t_UF'];
27 $t_canal = $_POST['t_canal'];
28 $t_ano = $_POST['t_ano'];
29
30 if ($t_bebida != "Todos") {
31   $query_final .= " AND BEBIDA = '$t_bebida'";};
32  
33 if ($t_ano != "Todos") {
34    $query_final .= " AND ANO = '$t_ano'";};
35
36 if ($t_uf != "Todos") {
37    $query_final .= " AND UF = '$t_uf'";};
38
39 if ($t_canal != "Todos") {
40   $query_final .= " AND CANAL = '$t_canal'";};
41  
42 $query = $query_init . $query_final;
```

But when I'm receiving "todos" for t_bebida, I get this error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: query_final in /***/ on line 36

Any help?

Short time ago, I've asked a question about treatment of $_POST.

But there they answered me that I need to reformulate my query and do some IFs to query run properly.

I have this situation:

A user will send by $_POST this vars:

```
t_bebida
t_uf
t_canal
t_ano
```

Each one of these vars can come with a value of "Todos".

To exemplify the situation, this is my code:

```
$query_init = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE";

// $_POST to PHP var.
$t_bebida = $_POST['t_bebida'];
$t_uf = $_POST['t_UF'];
$t_canal = $_POST['t_canal'];
$t_ano = $_POST['t_ano'];

//IF BEBIDA == todos
if ($t_bebida == "Todos") {
$query_final = " UF = '$t_uf' AND CANAL = '$t_canal' AND ANO = '$t_ano' ORDER BY BEBIDA ASC";}

//IF UF == todos
if ($t_uf == "Todos") {
$query_final = " BEBIDA = '$t_bebida' AND UF = '$t_uf' AND CANAL = '$t_canal' AND ANO = '$t_ano'";} 

//IF CANAL ==todos
if ($t_canal == "Todos") {
$query_final = " BEBIDA = '$t_bebida' AND UF = '$t_uf' AND ANO = '$t_ano'";}

//IF ANO == todos
if ($t_canal == "Todos") {
$query_final = " BEBIDA = '$t_bebida' AND UF = '$t_uf' AND CANAL = '$t_canal'";}

//IF BEBIDA + UF == todos
if ($t_bebida == "Todos" and $t_uf == "Todos") {
$query_final = " CANAL = '$t_canal' AND ANO = '$t_ano'";}

//IF BEBIDA + UF + CANAL == todos
if ($t_bebida == "Todos" and $t_uf == "Todos" and $t_canal == "Todos") {
$query_final = " ANO = '$t_ano'";}

//IF BEBIDA + UF + ANO == todos
if ($t_bebida == "Todos" and $t_uf == "Todos" and $t_ano == "Todos") {
$query_final = " CANAL = '$t_canal'";}

//IF BEBIDA + CANAL == todos
if ($t_bebida == "Todos" and $t_canal == "Todos"){
$query_final = " UF = '$t_uf' AND ANO = '$t_ano'";}

//IF BEBIDA + CANAL + ANO == todos
if ($t_bebida == "Todos" and $t_canal == "Todos" and $t_ano == "Todos"){
$query_final = " UF = '$t_uf'";}

//IF BEBIDA + ANO == todos
if ($t_bebida == "Todos" and $t_ano == "Todos"){
$query_final = " UF = '$t_uf' AND CANAL = '$t_canal'";}

//IF UF + CANAL == todos
if ($t_uf == "Todos" and $t_canal == "Todos"){
$query_final = " BEBIDA = '$t_bebida' AND ANO = '$t_ano'";}

//IF UF + ANO == todos
if ($t_uf == "Todos" and $t_ano == "Todos"){
$query_final = " BEBIDA = '$t_bebida' AND CANAL = '$t_canal'";}

//IF UF + CANAL + ANO == todos
if ($t_uf == "Todos" and $t_canal == "Todos" and $t_ano == "Todos"){
$query_final = " BEBIDA = '$t_bebida'";}

//IF CANAL + ANO == todos
if ($t_uf == "Todos" and $t_ano == "Todos"){
$query_final = " BEBIDA = '$t_bebida' AND CANAL = '$t_canal'";}

//IF NONE == todos
if ($t_bebida != "Todos" and $t_uf != "Todos" and $t_ano != "Todos" and $t_UF != "Todos" and $t_canal != "Todos"){
$query_final = " BEBIDA = '$t_bebida' AND UF = '$t_uf' AND CANAL = '$t_canal' AND ANO = '$t_ano'";}

// Build-UP query
$query = $query_init . $query_final;
```

This is not working for me, It works only for 't_bebida == todos' or 'none == todos'.

So, what I'm facing is that I'm not correctly structuring IFs to the query.

Can someone help me to figure it out?...

Thanks,

Comment: Have you met [*Bobby Tables*](http://xkcd.com/327/) ?

Comment: what do you mean by it's not working for you?

Comment: Oh, your logic is all wrong....

Comment: I'm sorry @alfasin, but I'm not a pro. If I'm totally wrong and doing stupid stuff that needs to be sanitized, this means that I need stackoverflow help, or more specifically, help from people who cares to help others.

Comment: Yes @user623952, my logic is all wrong, and I can't figure how to fix it. It's not that I'm lazy or want to others do my job, but I'm newbie and I want to learn.

Comment: lol @alfasin...+1...Sanitize your input, or you're wide open to sql injection attacks.

Comment: @Ycavazin - no one is attacking you.  And if you're learning, you should try to learn the correct and most current way.  Prepared statements aren't hard at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translation of [Todos](http://translate.google.com/#es/en/Todos).

Better to rewrite your code. And use [this feature](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8149142/1503018).

```
$query_init = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE 1=1";
$query_final = '';

if ($t_bebida != "Todos") 
    $query_final .= " AND BEBIDA = '$t_bebida'";

if($t_ano != "Todos")
    $query_final .= " AND ANO = '$t_ano'";

if ($t_uf != "Todos")
    $query_final .= " AND UF = '$t_uf'";

if ( $t_canal != "Todos")
    $query_final .= " AND CANAL = '$t_canal'";

$query = $query_init . $query_final;
```

Also do not forget to use prepared statements.

Comment: Thanks @sectus, I'll try this fix, and post the results.

Comment: I'm glad you could make sense of the logic.  I didn't even think to check google translate.  I was trying to re-write it myself but I couldn't figure out what was supposed to be happening.  Good Job!

Comment: Thanks @sectus, this code worked beautifully! I'm reading about PDO and Prepared Statements to avoid injection, but this is a next step. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

This is just to show how your if's can be enhanced . You should better look into using PDO or MySQLi .

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE 1 ";

$t_bebida = $_POST['t_bebida'];
$t_uf = $_POST['t_UF'];     //  Is this t_UF or t_uf ?
$t_canal = $_POST['t_canal'];
$t_ano = $_POST['t_ano'];

if( $t_bebida <> "Todos" )
{
    $query .= " AND `BEBIDA` = '$t_bebida'";
    $order_by_column = "`BEBIDA`";
}

if( $t_uf <> "Todos" )
{
    $query .= " AND `UF` = '$t_uf'";
    $order_by_column = "`UF`";
}

if( $t_canal <> "Todos" )
{
    $query .= " AND `CANAL` = '$t_canal'";
    $order_by_column = "`CANAL`";
}

if( $t_ano <> "Todos" )
{
    $query .= " AND `ANO` = '$t_ano'";
    $order_by_column = "`ANO`";
}

$query .= " ORDER BY " .$order_by_column ." ASC";   //  LIMIT 100

echo query;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I fixed it out with @sectus answer, and now I'll study about PDO and prepared statments. Thanks again!.