# Strange condition in Mysql query

Tags: mysql

Basically I have to edit someone's else code and the query is:

```
DELETE  FROM some_table WHERE 1
```

Googling around didn't find anything similar.

I can't understand the condition. Would someone explain it to me please?

Comment: Surely they want to enforce the good practice of always adding a where clause. Very frecuently users accidentally delete ALL the table just to forget the condition. Some frontends give a warning to prevent this situation.

Comment: it cames from the phpmyadmin default `DELETE` queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, it would delete all the rows (because `1` is true).  If you want to delete all rows, it is often more efficient to use `truncate table`:

```
truncate table some_table
```

One reason you might want to generate a statement with `where 1` is so you can add additional clauses afterwards.

Comment: Though pretty much everyone was telling the same thing I am accepting this answer because it's exactly why it was used in my piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

The `WHERE 1` condition means that there's no condition. Delete everything from table. It is equivalent to `DELETE FROM some_table`. In other words, the condition says that "where true" (1 evaluates to true) so it means everywhere...

Answer (score 1):

This will delete all the rows from the table, because `where 1` will be true for all the rows. It is like `while(1)` loop, which is always true.

Many times people put such default conditions at the top of a where condition as it enables them to freely chop and change the rest of the conditions. More details can be found in answers of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149142/where-1-1-statement).

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM some_table WHERE 1
```

is like

```
DELETE EVERYTHING FROM some_table
```

WHERE 1 will be true for all the rows as 1 equals true.

The database looks like this to Bob when it checks for the above

```
Mysql - "Hey Bob, can you DELETE some_table WHERE items equal 1?"
Bob - "Yes, a moment.."
Mysql - "Wa..wait..! What's 1, Bob?"
Bob - "Ah yeah, in my world 1 is everything that evaluates to True, 
          and that's the default state of a self-standing row, 
            but lemme check it for you.."

*Bob is checking the rows...*
row1 <-- 1

row2 <-- 1

row3 <-- 1

Bob - "So, I checked the table and everything in there is 1 (or True), 
           let's delete all some_table's content!"
Mysql - "Agreed."
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you see such conditions (which always evaluates to TRUE in Mysql - other RDMS may give you "invalid relational operator" error) when query is built dynamically. For instance,

```
String basicQuery = "DELETE FROM table1 WHERE 1 " ; 
-- I'd use something less mysql specific, e.g WHERE (1=1) which works for every RDMS
if (some_condition) 
{
   basicQuery = basicQuery+ " AND field1 = :param1"; 
}
if (other_condition) 
{
   basicQuery = basicQuery+ " AND field2 = :param2"; 
} 
// etc
```