# Multiple Keyword/Condition Search (AND, OR , No value Input tag ) PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm beginner in PHP MySQL. It's gonna be too long to explain, I having much not likely `error` but something error in  `conditions`. I found that trigger the problem, I found that it's more likely in **`AND`**, **`OR`**, **`Input tag no value`**.

**Scenario**
I have a search form with multiple inputs.
*Let's pretend this is the search form, I can't send image due to low reputation.*

> **G-Number:** [________] (This is Unique key in my database) 
>   **Name:** [__________] 
>   **Virtual Number:** [__________] 
>   **[Search button]**

**Using OR condition** 
Let's pretend that I input `123456` in **G-Number** will query like this:

> ________________________________________
>   |   G-Number   |     Name      |     Virtual Number    |
> ----------------------------------------------------------------
>   |   123456       |     John        |          001abc           |

So  if only input `John` in **Name**, and `123456` in **G-Number**. The error here it shows all  `John` even I input `123456` in G number.
 
**Sample Result like this**

> GNumber | Name | Virtual Number 
>    123456   | John    | 001abc 
>    535243  | John    | 002efg
>    965235  | John    | 002efg

**Using AND condition**

Here I need to fill up all the search form so it can search it, If I leave a blank it will say base from my system that `No result Found`
Basically if I input only `123456` in **G-Number** and leave the  `input` blanks it can't search result so it's look like the code is this in `SQL query`

```
SELECT * FROM `subscribers` WHERE `fName` = '' AND `gNumber` = '123456' AND `virtualNumber` = '';
```

So basically the value of leave input form was space or like this `''`.

That's why I'm looking for help and tips what should I do here, I don't want to use `**MySQLi**` and `**PDO**` now. I'm still practicing `**MySQL**`. All I want here function multiple keyword search.

**Here is my codes:**

```
**HTML FORM**
         <form class="form-inline" role="form" method="GET"  id="searchform">
          <div class="form-group">

          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="gnumber" placeholder="Number" style="margin-right: 2em;" >
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name"  placeholder="Input First or Last Name" style="width: 300px;margin-right: 2em;">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="virtual"  placeholder="Virtual Number" style="margin-right: 2em;">


          <br/><h5 style="float:right;"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-theme02" name="search" ><i class="fa fa-check">Search</i></button></h5>

          </div>

**THE PHP CODE**
  if (isset($_GET['search'])) {

        $gnum = htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['gnumber']));
        $name = htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name']));
        $vr = htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['virtual']));



        if (empty($globe) && empty($name) && empty($vr)) {
         echo "<script> alert('Please select atleast 1 filter!')</script>";  
         exit;
        } else {
       $sql =  "SELECT * FROM `subscribers` WHERE `fName` = '".$name."' OR `gNumber` =  '".$gnum."' OR `virtualNumber` = '".$vr."'    ";
        }

      if ($result=mysql_query($sql)) {
          $query_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
             if($query_num_rows == 0){ 
                echo "<script> alert('No Records Found!')</script>"; 

      } else {

       while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      // echo of result table is here.
```

**Thank you.**

$sql =  "SELECT * FROM `subscribers` WHERE";

```
        if (empty($globe) && empty($name) && empty($vr)) {
         echo "<script> alert('Please select atleast 1 filter!')</script>";  
         exit;
        } 
        if(!empty($name)){
            $sql .append(`fName` = '".$name."'); 
        } 
        if(!empty($gnum)){
                  $sql .append(`gNumber` = '".$gum."');
        }
```

You have to follow such type of approach. I really do not know the Php syntax. But approach should be like this.

Comment: why do you not generate this sql query dynamically. Let say if GNumber field is empty then exclude it from sql statement. like $sql =  "SELECT * FROM `subscribers` WHERE `fName` = '".$name."' AND `virtualNumber` = '".$vr."'    ";

Comment: @Naveen : Thank you but how to exlude, what do you mean?

Comment: @Naveen: Got it, more `else if` right? long process right?

Comment: Because your code is specific towards parameters. Otherwise generally  get list of parameter in map and iterate through that with few line of code. It also save your time for future too. Reason you do not need to add more else if as you filter parameters grow.

Comment: @Naveen: Got it you can post this now i'm using your tip like this if (!empty)

Comment: @Naveen please don't attempt to answer questions by editing the question! Press the "Add an answer" button.

Comment: Do you know using WHERE 1=1 ?? search about this , you will get some idea.

Comment: @JJ-SAMA Accepting answer is another good way to say thanks.

Comment: sorry still have issues

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu can you elaborate?

Comment: If the list of conditions is not known at compile time and is instead built at run time, you don't have to worry about whether you have one or more than one condition. You can generate them all like:

`and <condition>`
and concatenate them all together. With the 1=1 at the start, the initial and has something to associate with.see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149142/where-1-1-statement and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242822/why-would-someone-use-where-1-1-and-conditions-in-a-sql-clause It may guide you.