# build tsql insert statements from database based on information from a single table

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio-2012, sql-insert

Assuming I have the following database / tables (Fk means foreign key to said table):

```
Table: Brand
Table: Customer (Primary Key {CustomerId}) [Fk Brand]
Table: Address [Fk Region] [Fk Customer]
Table: Region
```

If I have a "CustomerId" and direct access to the database, is there a way I can loop through the database without knowing any other tables except for the table my "CustomerId" exists in?

I want to generate the sql insert statements in the correct order to re-create the entire customer structure so that anything that has a Fk to the customer and anything the customer has a Fk on, will also be re-created.

I am fine with someone just giving me a link on a "how to" to something similar. The reason I want this is because I often get a request at work saying "x customer has y issue" and sometimes without getting that exact data into a testing database it can be almost impossible to figure out as you don't want to touch the data in production. So If I can run a program that will build the customer as it exists in production, it will make my life much easier.

I am sure this must be possible using C# and or Stored Sprocs in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a reference to all of the tables where a column is referred to using the following:

```
SELECT 
     ST.Name                AS  TableName 
    ,SC.name                AS  ColumnName
FROM
    sys.columns  AS SC

    INNER JOIN sys.tables AS ST

    ON SC.Object_ID = ST.Object_Id 

WHERE
    ST.Type = 'U'
AND
    SC.name = 'CustomerId'
```

Comment: I am assuming this will fail though if the fk column name does not exactly match the primary key name?

Comment: Is there anyway, using this to know the order in which things matter? For example, I might not be able to insert something into table Y if table X values have not been inserted into yet.

Comment: You can reference the sys.constraints table to get this information. I am working on a query to test this, and will post if I can get the query completed.

Comment: There is so much I don't know about sys tables. I hope you are able to build a query of some sort. Even if it does not work 100% I would still love to see it so I can learn!

Comment: Try looking at this question and answer.  Give you some good points to start working with.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/765867/list-of-all-index-index-columns-in-sql-server-db