# DMVs to get index configuration information

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I want to check whether all the tables in my Database has clusterd index on which type of column(eg:int) and whether the clustered index is on a single/multipe columns. I was not able to figure out which DMvs or Views to retreive this information. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below sql will give you list of the clusterd indexes and table name with few more detail.  you can modified this to get to you results.

```
SELECT 'ClusteredIndexName' = SI.Name, 
       'TableName' = SO.Name, 
       'ColumCount' = IK.IndexColumnCount,
       'IsUnique' = CASE WHEN SI.is_unique = 0 THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END
       ,SI.type_desc
FROM SYS.INDEXES SI                 

JOIN SYS.OBJECTS SO                 -- Joining on SYS.OBJECTS to get the TableName
  ON SO.OBJECT_ID = SI.Object_ID

JOIN (                              -- Joining on a Derived view to work out how many columns exist on the clustered index 
        SELECT 'IndexColumnCount' = MAX(KEY_ORDINAL), OBJECT_ID, index_id
        FROM SYS.INDEX_COLUMNS
        GROUP BY OBJECT_ID, index_id       
     )  AS IK                       
  ON IK.object_id = SI.Object_ID
 AND IK.index_id = SI.index_id  

WHERE SI.type_desc = 'CLUSTERED'    and                 
   SI.OBJECT_ID NOT IN (SELECT OBJECT_ID 
               FROM SYS.ALL_OBJECTS
               WHERE TYPE = 'S')        -- Not system tables
  AND SO.Type = 'U'
  AND SO.is_ms_shipped = 0
```

Comment: Thank you very much... This is what I was looking for. Shall we find the data type of the column(s) inculded in the index?

Comment: Please look this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/765867/list-of-all-index-index-columns-in-sql-server-db

Answer (score 0):

Sql Server Management Studio lets you see the definition of all indexes on a table. Find the table in the Tables folder, expand, and expand Indexes. Select Properties on a particular index to view columns and other properties.

Comment: Yes I know but i have a huge database with lot of indexes. Instead of searching through all of it do I have a query to get the information at once?

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM sys.indexes (I think, its been a while since I used SQL Server).