# Error on a unique non-clustered index

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, indexing

I am trying to move a field do a different position in the table (I'm just trying to get it in alphabetical order). When I click save, I get this error message (TaskID is the name of another field):

```
'tblTask' table
- Unable to create index 'idx_TaskID_notnull'.  
The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'dbo.tblTask' and the index name 'idx_TaskID_notnull'. The duplicate key value is (<NULL>).
The statement has been terminated.
```

I have one unique non-clustered index for TaskID that has the filter `TaskID IS NOT NULL`.

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

You're only allowed one of any value in a unique index, include `NULL` so if you have multiple rows with `NULL` values, that's why you would get the error.

I presume, because you say "brand new field" that you've just created the column. If you did so without also populating it, all of the values would be `NULL`.

The simplest way to take care of this is to:

1. Populate the appropriate value for the column, or at least whatever you want your default value to be if you don't know the appropriate one to start.
2. `ALTER` your column so that it is NOT NULL

   `alter table dbo.tbltask alter column taskid int not null`
3. Add a default constraint to your column so that it always has a value.

   `alter table tbltask add constraint df_taskid default (0) for taskid`

Alternatively, if you want all old rows in your table to be `NULL` and only new rows always be `NOT NULL` you can add a filtered index instead, since you're working with 2008 (or higher).

```
create unique nonclustered index idx_TaskID_notnull on dbo.tbltask (taskid) 
    where taskid is not null
```

Comment: I've filtered the index for non-null values, so it should allow nulls, right? Also the new field I am trying to allow NULLs in is a completely different field from the one in the error message. The new field is not included in any indexes and I have already populated it with data and set its default to a non-null value, not that I think that should matter since the error only mentions the TaskID field... I must be able to allow NULL values in TaskID while preventing duplicate non-NULL values.

Comment: @Mike Can you provide the definition for your index `idx_TaskID_notnull` in the question? That may help a good deal to resolve the difference. Your error is saying that you have a duplicate value in a key of the named index; would be good to look at what all are keys in the index.

Comment: Where do I go to find the definitions? SQL Server Management Studio seems to hide all SQL from me except in views... Though I can tell you TaskID is the only indexed key column there with no included columns. And the filter is `([TaskID] IS NOT NULL)`

Comment: @Mike That's a concern; you might not have permission. You can run this query to confirm: `SELECT 
     TableName = t.name,
     IndexName = ind.name,
     IndexId = ind.index_id,
     ColumnId = ic.index_column_id,
     ColumnName = col.name,
     ind.*,
     ic.*,
     col.* 
FROM 
     sys.indexes ind 
INNER JOIN 
     sys.index_columns ic ON  ind.object_id = ic.object_id and ind.index_id = ic.index_id 
INNER JOIN 
     sys.columns col ON ic.object_id = col.object_id and ic.column_id = col.column_id 
INNER JOIN 
     sys.tables t ON ind.object_id = t.object_id 
WHERE ind.name = 'name`

Comment: For completeness, that query above came from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/765867/list-of-all-index-index-columns-in-sql-server-db