# To delete the all record from table in android SQllite Database?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to delete the all record from the table in database, but I cannot delete. Can anybody help me?

**I am using this link [Delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000917/delete-all-from-table)**

```
   public void delete() 
   {
    String DELETEPASSCODE_DETAIL = "DELETE * FROM Payment;";
    db.execSQL(DELETEPASSCODE_DETAIL);
   }
```

am calling the delete function here

```
private void savepay() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            String check;

        webService calService=new  webService();
             dh.open();
             Cursor c = dh.pay();


            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),className+c.getString(1)+c.getString(2)+c.getString(3)+c.getString(4),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         check=  calService.paymentReceipt("PaymentReceipt",c.getString(1),c.getString(2),c.getString(3),c.getString(4),c.getString(5),"0");

             }
             while (c.moveToNext()); 
             dh.delete();//here i called delete function
             dh.close();



            }
```

Comment: SQlite does not require the * for DELETE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code should be like

```
public void delete() 
{
          String DELETEPASSCODE_DETAIL = "DELETE FROM Payment;";
          db.execSQL(DELETEPASSCODE_DETAIL);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Should be:

"DELETE FROM Payment;"

[image]

More details: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html

Comment: Please post the database schema.  Are you receiving any error?

Answer (score -1):

It should be `DELETE FROM Payment;` not `DELETE * FROM Payment;`
See Structure of Delete Query
[image]
see [How to write delete query](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html)