# Android : the distinguish between delete *from tablename where 1 = 1 and delete from tablename ?

Tags: android, sqlite

I don't know the meaning of  where 1 1?  Thanks fo your answer.

Comment: look into this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000917/delete-all-from-table)

Comment: Please find such similar question on Google search before asking here

Comment: It will help you when you are building dynamic WHERE clause.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why would someone use WHERE 1=1 AND <conditions> in a SQL clause?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242822/why-would-someone-use-where-1-1-and-conditions-in-a-sql-clause)

Comment: `WHERE 1=1 OR ....` is used in SQL injection attacks: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

Answer (score 1):

`1=1` is true for any row. Therefore, `DELETE FROM tablename WHERE 1=1` deletes all rows. `DELETE * ...` with the asterisk is syntactically incorrect in sqlite.

Also `DELETE FROM tablename` deletes all rows.

Answer (score 0):

their is no such statement like delete * from tablename where 1=1.

because where clause is used to give condition so that compiler can get the data according to that condition, u can write where columnname= value.
Inside this u can write the particular column name and value on bass of which u want to delete some data.