# 'WHERE 1 =1' in SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why would someone use WHERE 1=1 AND <conditions> in a SQL clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242822/why-would-someone-use-where-11-and-conditions-in-a-sql-clause)

I've been tasked with reviewing some SQL stored procedures and have seen many that look like the following:

```
SELECT 
  X, Y, Z 
FROM 
  Table
WHERE 
  1 = 1
ORDER BY
  X
```

Why would someone use '1 = 1' for the where clause?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242822/why-would-someone-use-where-11-and-conditions-in-a-sql-clause

Comment: @steinar - Thanks. I did try some searches, but had no luck. This is a dupe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's common in dynamic SQL, in order to append additional criteria to a WHERE clause.  Otherwise, it's useless and it is ignored by the optimizer.

Answer (score 2):

possibly to dynamically add conditions to the where clause.