# SQL Server where clause using In() vs Wildcard

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there any performance difference between query A and query B?

Query A

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable
WHERE 1 = 1 AND (SomeField LIKE '[1,m][6,e][n]%')
```

Query B

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable
WHERE 1 = 1 AND (SomeField IN ('16', 'Mens'))
```

Comment: First of all, they are not equivalent.

Comment: @vulkanino: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242822/why-would-someone-use-where-1-1-and-conditions-in-a-sql-clause

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first could be much slower. An index can't be used with `LIKE` unless there is a constant prefix, for example `LIKE 'foo%'`. The first query will therefore require a table scan. The second query however could use an index on `SomeField` if one is available.

The first query will also give the wrong results as it matches '1en'.

Comment: @Mark: Shouldn't the optimizer be smart enough to realize that `c LIKE 'Q[a-b]%'` could use the index? As it's the same as `c LIKE 'Qa%' or c LIKE 'Qb%'`?

Comment: My guess is the optimizer will only use the index for Q in LIKE 'Q[a-b]%'.