# SQL WHERE column = everything

Tags: mysql, sql

Is SQL able to do something along the lines of this: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = everything`

Comment: Just remove that part of the string. If you don't care of `column` value - don't even put it to `where`

Comment: if you do not need a column then remove entire WHERE definition

Comment: FWIW (some may find this of interest): If a `WHERE` is required (because, well, sometimes fickle systems require it sometimes...) then `WHERE 1=1` will "match everything". Likewise this can be extended (once again, for those fickle systems) `WHERE 1=1 OR c='don''t care'`...

Comment: @stevether Only that which is constrained via parameterized queries ;-)

Comment: I am trying to solve this problem for convenience.  I have 3 prepared statements that may or may not have 3 variables combined in the where clause.  Rather than write several prepared statements for the combinations of all 3 variable values (null, not null), I'd like to ignore a variable in the where clause if it's not there.

Comment: i've just run into this same issue as you. It seems silly from the outside (just drop the `where` clause) but it would make it easier with only needing to write one parameterized query, rather than a bunch of conditions. curious if anything has changed since 2012.

Comment: OMG i am so stupid @zerkms nailed it. I was whole day strugling with what to put in part for WHERE to match anything like * and i just realized i jut need to remove it :D

Comment: Is there a way to do it using `sequelize`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your question allow three intrepretations:

1. You don't care about the column: drop the it from the where clause (or drop the where clause alltogether, if this was the only subclause)
2. You want the column to be set, bit you don't care to what: Use `WHERE column IS NOT nULL`
3. You want a search, that can also display all records from a simple SQL template: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%$searchterm%'`

Comment: I have this problem and I can't see the answer here. 
My interpretation is this - I have a variable which I use to define the value of a column. BUT if that variable is 'all', I am not looking for the value 'all', rather the query act like the WHERE clause is not there. I do not want to necessarily write two queries. I am looking for a symbol, eg. '*' which looks for everything.

Comment: @gavin What's your programming language?

Comment: hi, MySQL. I have written 2 queries, but was interested in a value or symbol that meant EVERYTHING, much like the OP

Comment: Yes I am having this exact same need, and also I have not seen an answer as the LIKE clause doesn't return Nulls.

Comment: @gavin - Did you ever find a solution? I'm still looking for one. Frustrating that a wrong answer was accepted here.

Comment: @Truth - no, in the end I wrote two queries - `if (var=all){query without WHERE}else {query with WHERE = var}`

Comment: @gavin - Ha! I came up with a very similar solution before you wrote back. See below.

Comment: `You don't care about the column: drop the it from the where clause (or drop the where clause alltogether, if this was the only subclause)` - some times you just use a prepared statement which has a parameter in the where clause and you don't want to limit the result to particular value of the parameter in a particular case. That's when `where a = x and b = anything` would be useful if it was available.

Comment: @Ivan Abusing a prepared statement this way would be a huge mistake.

Answer (score 52):

For anyone who NEEDS the column name in the query for whatever reason (probably dynamic SQL), a nice alternative would be `SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = column`

This is very similar to `WHERE 1=1`, however it includes the column name, which my solution required, and maybe a few others will require as well.

Comment: My solution for a project I inherited, needed exactly this - Thank you so much

Comment: This doesn't work for null values, which is fine for my case of a composite key.

Answer (score 35):

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

If you're generating SQL dynamically, it's

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1=1
```

The `1=1` placeholder allows you to return all records, or substitute an actual condition if you're returning a subset or need additional conditional statements.

**See Also** 
[Why would someone use WHERE 1=1 AND <conditions> in a SQL clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242822/why-would-someone-use-where-1-1-and-conditions-in-a-sql-clause)

Comment: But if it's a prepared statement, 1=1 will not work as it is automatically escaped, no ?

Comment: If it is a prepared statement, doesn't it already have a WHERE?

Comment: I like the 1=1 solution!

Answer (score 11):

You can use column name itself in your query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN = COLUMN
```

for example:

```
SELECT * FROM Student WHERE YEAR = YEAR
```

or by using a Auxiliary parameter:

```
SELECT * FROM Student WHERE YEAR = (CASE WHEN @year IS NOT NULL THEN @year ELSE YEAR END)
```

so you can hold on "=" char

Comment: I like your first example the most. I have an object method that watches for user inputs. When the input is empty, it simply excludes the clause. This means the query is highly variant and difficult to test with. A wildcard match (or making it match itself) works, but I'm concerned that the reason MySQL doesn't do this is because of performance loss.

Answer (score 8):

Everything or anything?

You could use a wildcard I guess.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE "%"
```

Comment: Nope, you're wrong. `= '%'` means "the value exactly equal to one  percent char"

Comment: And you're wrong once again, because it wouldn't include `NULL` values

Comment: What is the point of that? Then just `SELECT * FROM table`. If you don't need a filter, then don't use a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: (I wonder what the point of that is... although, perhaps for some brittle SQL generators...)

Comment: I wanted to create some dynamic SQL, but that's fine, I know of a better way of doing it.

Comment: This is very useful! For those asking why, consider:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE field='22' OR field LIKE '%';`

This would return a fallback row if the desired row was not found

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = IF (? = '', column, ?);
```

Comment: Thanks @Truth, will give this a go

Comment: You may have solved the problem of having to write multiple queries, but what impact does this have upon that column's index?

Answer (score 3):

This is late but may be helpful to others

You can try this.

```
where 
    isnull([column], '') = CASE WHEN @column IS NULL THEN isnull([column], '') ELSE @column END
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you perhaps looking for the IN criteria operator?

```
SELECT * from table where column in (1,2,3,4,5) or column in ('value', 'value2', 'value3');
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I had this same issue too and the following solved my problem:

```
... where column = case when @variable = 'all' then column else @variable end
```

> **Keep it in mind that you must always send a default value**
>   , i set my default value as 'all'. So if i set `@variable = 'all'`, mysql reads it as :
>   `where column = column` which is the same thing as `where 1=1`

Answer (score 1):

I've faced this problem while developing dynamically composing query.
Here is my solution in short:

```
WHERE (column = ANY (SELECT distinct column) OR column IS NULL)
```

This works with NULL values and practically it is identical to empty WHERE statement. I use brackets in order to keep the ability to add more WHERE options using AND operator.

It means that this:

```
select count("objectId"), "source"
from "SomeTable"
where "createdAt" > '2020-07-06'
    and ("source" = any (select distinct "source") or "source" is null)
    and ("country" = any (select distinct "country") or "country" is null)
    and "channel" is not null
group by "source"
```

equals to this:

```
select count("objectId"), "source"
from "SomeTable"
where "createdAt" > '2020-07-06'
    and "channel" is not null
group by "source"
```

So I can make a query template:

```
...
    WHERE (column = {{filter_value}} )
...
```

and set `ANY (SELECT distinct column) OR column IS NULL)` as default value for {{filter_value}}

Answer (score 0):

If this helps anyone... just to point out, if you have a problem such as SELECT * FROM something WHERE (can be specific or everything) such as filtering stuff, 
you can use 
 `SELECT * FROM something as s WHERE (?1 = 0 OR ?1 = s.type = ?1)` 
 0 here is a just predefined for all, so feel free to change, i needed this while using JPA repositories with hibernate for filtering. You can't do this medicinally as suggested by a previous answer because of the safety with prepared statements. Where the ?1 corresponds to :

```
  Page<Something> filterSometing(Long type,Pageable pageable);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a ternary if operator for that field

```
" . ($variable == 'selected value' ? '' : "AND column='" . $variable . "' ") . "
```

So where you select all in the options in the html page this ^^ field will not run but when you select something this code will show up like `column='".$variable."'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
WHERE 1
```

1 is like in other language always true. So you have no filter

Answer (score 0):

FOR PROCEURES: if you send a parameter for the condition, you can define a constant value to get all rows For example you can say when i send `%` for it get all rows

`SELECT * FROM allstocks WHERE allstocks.storestockid=key1 OR '%'=key1`

you can replace `'%'` with `1` or anything you want

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this, you basically need to use `WHERE true`. Since MySQL doesn't accept true though, you have to substitute it for a number.

As integers, 0 is equal to false and 1 is equal to true.

This means, if you want to achieve "WHERE everything", you can simply use:

```
WHERE 1
```

You can also use something that always outputs as true, such as:

```
WHERE 1=1
```

or

```
WHERE 1+2-1=2
```

You can also just remove the WHERE declaration in general:

```
SELECT * FROM table;
```

instead of

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE 1=1;
```