# SQL WHERE column = everything (with Active Record)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In SQL you can create a dynamic SQL statement when the list of conditions (WHERE) is not known in advance, but is built at code execution. So sometimes I would like a subset of records (like ids matching an array), but in other cases I don't want the condition to be applied (hence return the whole list).

In pure SQL there is this solution:[Stackoverflow: SQL WHERE column = everything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825247/sql-where-column-everything)

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = id
```

More here: [Stackoverflow: Why would someone use WHERE 1=1 AND  in a SQL clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242822/why-would-someone-use-where-1-1-and-conditions-in-a-sql-clause)

How would I do this using the DSL from Active Record?

Comment: You forgot to add a link.

Comment: Think you might have hit "Ask Question" instead of "Post Answer"

Comment: Sorry, I added the link and rephrased the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of these will work: (as will many more)

```
.where(MyModel.arel_attribut(:id).eq(MyModel.arel_attribute(:id)))
# OR 
.where(Arel.sql("1=1"))
```

This "always true" type conditioning was generally used for query assembly in Stored Procedures or in String concatenation where you would always have a WHERE clause but then may not have any conditions e.g.

```
SET @sqlString = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1=1'
IF (@var IS NOT NULL) 
  SET @sqlString = @sqlString + ' AND "column" LIKE ''%' + @var + '%'' '

EXEC (@sqlString) 

# OR

sqlString = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1=1" 
if someCondition 
  sqlString = sqlString + " AND column = " + value 
end if
```

but all of this seems antiquated (especially in regards to Rails).

ActiveRecord avoids all of this by using a library called `Arel` which assembles the SQL just prior to execution.

ActiveRecord provides a convenience method (`#all`) to generate a similar concept of select everything. You can just call `MyModel.all` which will return a chainable `ActiveRecord::Relation` you can then apply conditions, or not, you can add ORDER BY, GROUP BY, LIMIT, HAVING, etc. statements, it is up to you in code and at runtime.

You can utilize this chainability to "assemble" these conditions as you see fit e.g.

```
q = MyModel.all 
q.where!(name: "engineersmnky") if find_my_name?
```

These calls do not even have to make "logical" sense in SQL statement order because `Arel` knows the order in which to assemble these statements in order to form a coherent query. e.g.

```
MyModel.having("COUNT(column) > 1")
  .order(:name)
  .group(:name)
  .select("name, COUNT(column) AS counter")
  .where(x: 12)
  .limit(2)
```

This is completely jumbled from a SQL standpoint but when the actual query is assembled it will be ordered correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Chaining `where` clauses in Rails is quite easy

```rb
dataset = User.all
dataset = dataset.where(name: "John") if filter_name?
dataset = dataset.where("age > ?", 20) if filter_age?
dataset
```