# How to return all row values for any given particular column in MYSQL Database table - meant to be used for dynamic SQL query calls on JDBC

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am working with a JDBC and am trying to figure out how to dynamically create queries - which is proving to be a rather challenging feat. What input can I put in a SQL query to have it return any input for a given column?

For example,

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE name = ?;
```

Essentially I want the previous statement to match

```
SELECT * FROM customers;
```

Instead of replacing the "Where name = ?", is there anything I can replace the ? with to get the database to return all rows with any value in the name column?

This is probably going to sound really stupid but I tried this,

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE name = *;
```

but that unfortunately did not work.

Comment: You mean like `name IS NOT NULL`, or something else? Please clarify.

Comment: `name = ? OR  1=1`

Comment: @Zircon No I don't want not null values, I want any and all values returned. That is empty strings, null values, non-null values, everything. The caveat is having the "WHERE name = ?" be included in the query call.

Comment: @Tom If you have to have exactly "WHERE name = ?" in your query then you are bound to use some special value as marker for "give me them all". Can you use additional query parameters?

Comment: @Leonid Yes you may use additional query parameters but I just need to know if there is a way to use the "WHERE name = ?" clause and still return everything. If not then I suppose my only choice is to remove that part of the string before making the query call.

Answer (score 1):

There is at least one solution:

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE name = coalesce(?, name);
```

However this method disables index search when ? is not null

EDIT: use coalesce instead of Oracle-specific nvl

EDIT2: this solution does NOT work for null values

Another option is just use second parameter as marker for "gimme more"

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE name = ? or ? = 1;
```

Comment: `nvl` is `oracle` not `mysql` function

Comment: You have not mentions mysql in the question. And it's not a real trouble. Just replace nvl with coalesce

Comment: The questions is clearly tagged with mysql

Comment: Ahhh, yes. Sorry, my bad

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I think I figured it out from [another post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825247/sql-where-column-everything) Essentially just call

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE name = name OR name IS NULL;
```

This worked for me.