# SqlCommand parameters are not substituting correctly

Tags: c#, sql, c#-4.0, parameters, sqlparameter

```
private SqlCommand createSQLQuery(SqlCommand command)
{
    string[] allTheseWords;
    if (textBoxAllTheseWords.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        allTheseWords = textBoxAllTheseWords.Text.Split(' ');
        string SQLQuery = "SELECT distinct [skullbase].[dbo].[patients].[name], [skullbase].[dbo].[patients].[dos], [skullbase].[dbo].[patients].[ACC2], [SKULLbase].[dbo].[fullreport].[mrn1], [SKULLbase].[dbo].[fullreport].[ACC], [skullbase].[dbo].[fullreport].[fullreport] FROM [skullbase].[dbo].[fullreport], [skullbase].[dbo].[patients] WHERE ";
        int i = 1;
        foreach (string word in allTheseWords)
        {
            command.Parameters.Add("@word" + i.ToString(), SqlDbType.Text).Value = word;
            SQLQuery = SQLQuery + " [skullbase].[dbo].[fullreport].[fullreport] LIKE @word" + i.ToString() + " AND ";
            i++;
        }
        SQLQuery = SQLQuery + " skullbase.dbo.patients.ACC2 = skullbase.dbo.fullreport.ACC";
        command.CommandText = SQLQuery;
    }
    MessageBox.Show(command.CommandText.ToString());
    return command;
}
```

The above is my query. The word "word" is not being substituted for the actual value.

---

```
allTheseWords = textBoxAllTheseWords.Text.Split(' ');
```

Comment: Cocoa Dev, where you are using or assigningthe value of `word`? change the command.Parameters.Add with `command.Parameters.AddWithValues(@word, "variable word");`

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have to set the `CommandText` of the `SqlCommand` prior to adding parameters. Also, this is going to create an invalid query anyway... after you exit your loop and append the next string, you're going to have `... AND AND skullbase.dbo.patients.Acc2 = ...`

Comment: Check out for how you can use better if you have to add some conditions to `Where` clause http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242822/why-would-someone-use-where-1-1-and-conditions-in-a-sql-clause

Comment: I am interested in knowing what values are stored in the `string[] allTheseWords;` this is not how you build a Parameterized query by the way..

Comment: the values are from a textbox. allTheseWords = textBoxAllTheseWords.Text.Split(' ');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters, when you quote your parameter reference in your SQL CommandText (e.g.  ...`[fullreport] = '@word'`...) you are actually just using the literal value `'@word'`.  It is not being interpreted as a parameterized query.  To do that you would just use ...`[fullreport] = @word`...)

Secondly, I do not -think- you can assign multiple parameters with the same parameter name as you are doing in the loop.  Each parameter you add should have a unique name.

Comment: how do I add single quotes around the data

Comment: I removed the single quotes and same issue. It's not being interpreted as the actual value of word

Comment: Wait...did you modify the code to use LIKE instead of equality?  Also, if you are looping through a list of words and adding criterea that [fullreport] is LIKE (or EQUAL) to the words in the list, then you are potentially going to cause the WHERE to evaluate to false because it most likely won't be LIKE or EQUAL to all words..unless you are using LIKE and embedding wildcards in your words.  At this point I'm a little confused about the goal.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the same parameter name for each word. You should be using a different name for each one. You might consider appending an index or something else like that to make it a unique parameter name.

Comment: I updated the code so that the parameters are different but it still doesn't work