# Need help to build query

Tags: java, oracle10g

I am trying to write logic for advanced search which has lot of fields. Based on user inputs I have to build the query dynamically. The oracle query has exists clause also.

At present I have a chain of switch cases which helps me in forming the query. But this has become very complex procedure, editing the logic to build a query has become very difficult.

Other than switch case is there any other way to build query dynamically. Please  let me know

Comment: Have you think in generating a class that does the 'Query Building' due to parameter and data you give to it. for example, create a class, that has a method called addrestriction wich recives the information of a where clause, incluiding columm, operator and value and then implement a method called toSQL that generates the SQL query as a String for you to use it? you can SQandal try [here](http://code.google.com/p/sqandal/)

Answer (score 0):

Just generic suggestion adding `1=1` in where clause makes thing easier.
This might help [Why would someone use WHERE 1=1 AND <conditions> in a SQL clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242822/why-would-someone-use-where-1-1-and-conditions-in-a-sql-clause)
PS: Also update your question with specific problem otherwise it is very likely to be get closed.

Answer (score 0):

There is EasyQuery (http://devtools.korzh.com/easyquery/) solution but
it's implemented for ASP.NET as far as I know.
However, they have a jQuery-based client-side library which could be
useful in your case.