# Merging when using SQL GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-merge

my data in the mySQL DB looks like this (but not only this 4, i have many persons which are appearing more then once, but with different qualifications and different modified dates

[image: the data i have in my database]

Selection would be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table where person_id=1 GROUP BY person_id
```

so, if i make this selection and i group by person_id i get something like this:

[image: my result after selection an group by]

is there any possibility to group by the person id, but to say: ok, give me the last modified qualification? normally i don't have the `person_id` in the where SQL statement.
so i want all persons from my selection but only the result with the last modified qualification
( I hope I explained it well eonough so you understand what the problem is )

(my selection is of course much more complicated then the one i showed, this is just for showing you what I'm doing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use a subquery to return the `max` modified date for each `person_id` and then join that result to your table to get the rows with the max date:

```
select t1.id, 
  t1.person_id,
  t1.name,
  t1.qualification,
  t1.created,
  t1.modified,
  t1.version
from yourtable t1
inner join
(
  select person_id, max(modified) MaxMod
  from yourtable
  group by person_id
) t2
  on t1.person_id = t2.person_d
  and t1.modified = t2.maxmod
```

Comment: this sounds more like what i want, i will give it a try, thanks!

Comment: looks like it works, but the performance is so totally unacceptable, i will make a simpler SQL call - and then do the optimation in java. but thanks anyway @bluefeet

Comment: @Joerg do you have any indexes on the table?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the last modified entry of a specific person then just do

```
select * from table
where person_id = 1
order by modified desc
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

I misunderstood the question and i will update the answer

Try this (assuming you want the last modified qualification  **for each** person):

```
SELECT 
   person_id,
   qualification
FROM 
   table as a
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT 
     person_id,
     MAX(modified) as za_date
   FROM 
     table
   GROUP BY 
     person_id
) as tmp 
  ON a.person_id = tmp.person_id
  AND a.modified = tmp.za_date
```

If you want the last modified qualification for **all** persons :

```
SELECT
   qualification
FROM
   table
WHERE modified = (
       SELECT 
           MAX(modified)
       FROM
           table  
   )
```

Comment: its just a standard to format queries to have 
WHERE 1 
  AND cond1 
  AND cond2

its more readeable this way

Comment: [The main purpose of "WHERE 1" (or "WHERE 1=1") seems to be dynamic filtering](http://stackoverflow.com/a/242831/17117960). I would not advise using this for all queries everywhere. It's not more readable if for no other reason than it is an extra bit of code to read that does nothing (and some people may think you were trying to do something else, but mistyped, or may not understand it).

Comment: yeah ur right, if you have no AND conditions there no purpose in using it but for me its the force of habit :)

Comment: Why all these `WHERE 1`? Do they serve a purpose? Why don't you add `HAVING 1` as well?

Comment: Due to the many complaints i removed all `WHERE 1` as I've said before its a force of habit and from my pov i do not deserve down vote just for having a different query writing standard then others :)