# Why do I get syntax error when I update from MYSQL?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

In order to receive the parameters and update the data, I put the fake data in and run the update.

```sql
        UPDATE
        TB_PUSH_MESSAGE
        SET 1=1
        <if test="status != ''">
        , status = #{status}
        </if>
        <if test="body != null">
        , body = #{body}
        </if>
        WHERE
        seq_no = #{seq_no}
```

but it's get error

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your
>   SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use near '1=1
>                 , status = '0'
>
> ```
>           WHERE       seq_no = '1'' at line 3
> ```

How do I solve this problem if I can't put fake data in it?

Comment: It seems to me the error is in the '1'', there's an extra '

Comment: SET 1=1, here you are trying to update 1. what is 1 here(Left hand side) ? it is variable ?

Comment: @vc73  The '1=1' data is fake data for putting in commas.

Comment: @Ravindra The '1=1' data is fake data for putting in commas.

Comment: At least related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37665646/update-equivalent-of-where-1-1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be your `1 = 1` statement. In this case, first `1` is treated as "column number one in the table `TB_PUSH_MESSAGE`". So you can read this line as `set seq_no = 1`, which is most probably incompatible with type of the column.

[update equivalent of WHERE '1' = '1'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37665646/update-equivalent-of-where-1-1) — this question seems to be helpful/related/duplicate.

Comment: Then, how can you complete this sentence without adding fake data?

Comment: Maybe `set seq_no = seq_no` if you want this first "without comma" statement? :)