# SSRS: How to find which reports have subreports?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a lot of SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) reports (*.rdl). I want to know which of these reports are using subreports. How can I do that? Looking at an easier way instead of opening each report and figuring out if a subreport is being used.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of solution are you looking for? You can interrogate RDL files, or reports DB. The `ReportServer` DB has the table called `Catalog` and you should be able to link children to parents in there.

Comment: I dont want to open RDL files 1 by 1 to see if they have a sub report. How to query the `Catalog` table for parent and child? I tried using its `ItemID` and `ParentID` columns thinking that a report with a subreport will be different than a report without a subreport but thats not the case.

Comment: If my answer sorted you out, can you please click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think this should provide you with what you need (With thanks to [Bret Stateham](http://bretstateham.com/extracting-ssrs-report-rdl-xml-from-the-reportserver-database/) ):

```
 --The first CTE gets the content as a varbinary(max)
 --as well as the other important columns for all reports,
 --data sources and shared datasets.
 WITH ItemContentBinaries AS
 (
   SELECT
      ItemID,Name,[Type]
     ,CASE Type
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Report'
        WHEN 5 THEN 'Data Source'
        WHEN 7 THEN 'Report Part'
        WHEN 8 THEN 'Shared Dataset'
        ELSE 'Other'
      END AS TypeDescription
     ,CONVERT(varbinary(max),Content) AS Content
   FROM ReportServer.dbo.Catalog
   WHERE Type IN (2,5,7,8)
 ),
 --The second CTE strips off the BOM if it exists...
 ItemContentNoBOM AS
 (
   SELECT
      ItemID,Name,[Type],TypeDescription
     ,CASE
        WHEN LEFT(Content,3) = 0xEFBBBF
          THEN CONVERT(varbinary(max),SUBSTRING(Content,4,LEN(Content)))
        ELSE
          Content
      END AS Content
   FROM ItemContentBinaries
 )
 --The outer query gets the content in its varbinary, varchar and xml representations...
 ,VarcharContent as
 (
 SELECT
    ItemID,Name,[Type],TypeDescription
   ,Content --varbinary
   ,CONVERT(varchar(max),Content) AS ContentVarchar --varchar
   ,CONVERT(xml,Content) AS ContentXML --xml
 FROM ItemContentNoBOM
 )
 SELECT * FROM VarcharContent where ContentVarchar like '%<subreport%'
```

Answer (score 2):

The following query below will return a list of deployed reports that have subreports. Here's the [Microsoft reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/reports/find-the-report-definition-schema-version-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017) and a [link for referencing older versions of SSRS](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robertbruckner/2009/03/03/subreport-usage/). It looks like the only difference is changing the version of SSRS in `XMLNAMESPACES`  part of the CTE.

#### Query to return all subreports

```
WITH
XMLNAMESPACES 
( 
    'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition' AS rdl
)
, 
report_list
AS
(
    SELECT 
          [ReportID] = cat.[ItemID]
        , [ReportName] = cat.[Name]
        , [ReportPath] = cat.[Path]
        , [xmlColumn] = CAST(CAST(cat.[Content] AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS XML)
    FROM  
        [ReportServer].[dbo].[Catalog] AS cat
    WHERE 
        1=1
        AND cat.[Content] IS NOT NULL
        AND cat.[Type] = 2 
)
SELECT 
      rpt.[ReportID]
    , rpt.[ReportName]
    , rpt.[ReportPath]
    , [SubReportName] = srpt.x.value('(//rdl:ReportName)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(256)')
FROM 
    report_list AS rpt
    CROSS APPLY xmlColumn.nodes('//rdl:Subreport') AS srpt(x);
```

Comment: If you put `1=1` at the top of a `WHERE` condition, it enables you to freely change the rest of the conditions when debugging a query. The SQL query engine will end up ignoring the `1=1` so it should have no performance impact. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/242822/9059424)