# MYSQL - SELECT products WHERE parent_category is active

Tags: php, mysql, categories, parent

assuming we have a database category structure like this

```
# Categories Table
| category_id | parent_category_id | status |

# Products Table
| product_id | category_id |
```

how do i get the list of products in a category **only if** the `parent_category_id` has an active `status = 1` ?

i guess i could use some sub-query in the `SELECT` statement, but i don't know how! :(

something like:

```
SELECT p.*, (SELECT * FROM ? WHERE ? ) AS x 
FROM products AS p 
    LEFT JOIN categories AS c ON p.category_id = c.category_id 
WHERE ... 
AND p.product_id = '?' 
AND ...
```

Thank you in advance for any advice!

> NB: i'm using PHP as backend language, just in case i need some sort
>   of data manipulation to pass to the mysql query.

Comment: What happen if the category doesnt have parent category?

Comment: Not sure whats the reason behide `WHERE 1=1` ? Because it's always true or 1 for the matter.. Also using filtering on a left table which is not a `IS NULL` check will cause the `LEFT JOIN` to be filterd as a `INNER JOIN` instead..  Can't say if  that's a problem here because off missing SQL code..

Comment: Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242822/why-would-someone-use-where-1-1-and-conditions-in-a-sql-clause

Comment: @Raymond Nijland: 1=1 just a dummy segment of text, i have just replaced with ...! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try not to use subquery, because it can affect the speed of loading data

maybe it can help

```
SELECT *
FROM categories c
INNER JOIN products p ON p.category_id=c.category_id
WHERE c.status = 1
```

Comment: To format as `code`, select the text and press `ctrl-k`  or add 4 spaces before each line

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.* FROM products p
INNER JOIN categories child ON child.category_id = p.category_id
INNER JOIN categories parent ON parent.category_id = child.parent_category_id
WHERE parent.status=1
```

Comment: If you use `WHERE`,  `LEFT JOIN` become `INNER JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

Here a example query, I don't use left join or join, becasue you require that the record exists in order to get the status.

```
SELECT 
   *
FROM
   products, categories
WHERE
   products.category_id = categories.category_id
   AND status = '1'
```

Comment: that's your preference. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3480/what-is-more-efficient-a-where-clause-or-a-join-with-million-plus-row-tables

Answer (score 0):

First you have to get all active categories

```
SELECT child.*
FROM Categories child
JOIN Categories parent
  ON child.parent_category_id = parent.category_id 
 AND parent.status = 1
```

But you also need the root categories with not parent_id

```
SELECT *
FROM Categories
WHERE parent_category_id IS NULL
  AND status = 1
```

So you UNION both

```
SELECT *
FROM Categories child
JOIN Categories parent
  ON child.parent_category_id = parent.category_id 
 AND parent.status = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM Categories
WHERE parent_category_id IS NULL
  AND status = 1
```

Now you get the products for those categories

```
SELECT *
FROM (  ... UNION ALL ... ) active_categories
JOIN Products
 ON active_categories.category_id = Product.category_id
```