# Hibernate backend criterion query contains : where(1=1) what does it means?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Executing below line of codes:

```
Criteria cri = dc.getExecutableCriteria(this.session);

            int start = (p.getCurrentPage() - 1) * p.getPageSize();
            int end = p.getPageSize();
            cri.setFirstResult(start);
            cri.setMaxResults(end);

            result = cri.list();
```

when cri.list() executes I have check for the sql hibernate executes from the logs,

```
Hibernate: select * from 
( 
select this_.ID as ID175_0_, 
his_.NAME as NAME175_0_,
 this_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPT3_175_0_, 
 this_.VALUE as VALUE175_0_, 
 this_.STATE as STATE175_0_, 
 this_.ATTR1 as ATTR7_175_0_, 
 this_.ATTR2 as ATTR8_175_0_, 
 this_.ATTR3 as ATTR9_175_0_, 
 this_.ATTR4 as ATTR10_175_0_, 
 this_.ATTR5 as ATTR11_175_0_, 
 this_.LASTUSER as LAST12_175_0_, 
 this_.LASTTIME as LAST13_175_0_, 
 this_.POLICY as POLICY175_0_ 
 from TestDB.TestTable this_ 
  where (1=1) 
 and 
 this_.VALUE18 is null 
 order by lower(this_.NAME) asc, this_.ID desc ) where rownum <= ?
```

what does where (1=1) over here means??

Comment: It means "Here is a space where an extra condition might go, but since we don't have one, here's something that is always true."

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242822/why-would-someone-use-where-1-1-and-conditions-in-a-sql-clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what does where (1=1) over here means??

It's the same as not having a WHERE clause at all. All rows pass the test.

You'll see this in code that auto-generates WHERE clauses and either wants to always output one even if there are no criteria, or always starts out with that kind of all-rows-match criterion and then adds on any others via AND (so the code doesn't have to keep track of whether to output WHERE prior to the criterion or AND).