# USE WHERE 1=1 SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

In several codes on the web I have found the following sentence

```
SELECT *
  FROM <TABLE>
 WHERE 1=1  
   AND ....
```

I can't understand what purpose this comparison has to do.

Comment: That is usually inserted by automatically generated code.  It makes is slightly easier to add conditions just using `AND <condition>`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242822/why-would-someone-use-where-1-1-and-conditions-in-a-sql-clause

Comment: When you start with a WHERE 1=1, you can dynamically add new filters with just AND...

Comment: This is because it's useful for adding and removing conditions in code. It's really helped.

Comment: It's used by lazy programmers that generate SQL statements dynamically and don't want to keep track if they already added a condition or not