# Laravel eloquent turns certain clauses into 1=1. Is there a way to disable that?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

When using the query builder, if you give eloquent a clause that ends up being an identity, something like

```php
$foo = [];
$query->whereNotIn('column', $foo);
```

it translates that clause to `1=1` when it builds the query, at least for MySQL. Are there any config options to alter this behavior? I realize it would be ideal to check if `$foo` is empty before adding it to the query, but I think it would make more sense to just ignore the clause instead of turning it into `1=1` so I would like to know if there is any way to control that.

```
>>> echo User::whereNotIn('id',[])->toSql()
select * from `users` where 1 = 1
```

I'd rather that just evaluate to

```
select * from `users`
```

Comment: I would not worry about this. Sql engines understand that there is no need to actually do any where checks in a case like this ... the actual query plan will execute just as you desire!

Comment: This has been discussed 13 years ago here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242822/why-would-someone-use-where-1-1-and-conditions-in-a-sql-clause

Comment: @ManuelGlez  it sounds like the accepted answer of `With the 1=1 at the start, the initial and has something to associate with.` is basically moot since eloquent is smart enough to figure out how to generate a valid query either way. So wth, why is the 1=1 still there?

Comment: I think that the purpose of 1=1 is to give a simple valid expression that return true, but the really interesting is that `1=1` is accompanied by a **Where** or an **And**. How did eloquent resolve your expression with an empty array like User::whereNotIn('id',[]) ??