# why 0 is include in ngIf condition

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I was given a project developed by some other developer. He is no more working in this company. When I was going through the code, I saw one line of angular code.

```
*ngIf=" 0 && test1>120 && test2<900"
```

can someone tell me why 0 is included in this condition? what is the use of this type of statement?

Comment: Looks like a dead template. `0` will always be falsy with any number of `&&`

Comment: Either it was generated or the author has written it in a way to easily compose expressions and build it dynamically. Similar strategy to this except this was to be disabled: https://stackoverflow.com/q/242822

Comment: I imagine that is a "test": In anytime, someone want to check a component without this div and forgot remove after make the test. E.g. you can check something in code and write `if (false && condition){...}..others instructions..` to be sure not execute the code under the div. If you forget after make the test remove the false, your code never work property. Well, this can be about a part not yet implemented/checked and instead enclosed by comments use a *ngIf="false".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*ngIf="0"` is equivalent to `*ngIf="false"`.

So, `0 && test1>120 && test2<900` will evaluate to `false`.

The `*ngIf` was probably added to hide dead or experimental code.

Comment: ok. but here is what I understand that condition wants to check whether test1>120 and test2<900. if both are true then the rest of the code work. then by including 0, this will be always false? I am right? pls, comment ...

Comment: Yes, if `test1>120 && test2<900` evaluates to `true`, adding a `&& 0` will make the entire statement `false`. The `*ngIf` was probably added to hide dead or experimental code.

Comment: Thank you @brian-bianchi. This was for hiding one div for some reason from the live code.